# Reusing an jQuery UI dialog clears all its fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Using jQuery-UI dialog to get some input from user.
When pressing the `Esc` key the dialog closes without clearing its fields. When clicking `Save` or `Cancel` the fields get cleared.
This is fine except that I'm using watermark textbox for some fields and I don't want them to get cleared as the rest.

Should I change the code that clears the fields (I can't seems to find it...)?
Should I initalized the watermark textbox each time before opening the dialog?

The dialog javacript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#GetSomeData").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: "550px",
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
            // saving data to DB
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What watermark plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using http://jquery-watermark.googlecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the watermark once, and clone the dialog content every time you open it.

```
$(function () {
    // init watermark for #GetSomeData here

    var dialog = $("#GetSomeData").clone().appendTo('body').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: "550px",
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                // saving data to DB
                dialog.dialog("destroy").remove();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                dialog.dialog("destroy").remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This destroies the rebuilds the dialog every time, isn't this resources consuming? Do you know where the clearing of the fields takes place inside the jQuery code? Maybe I could just change it a bit.

Comment: It's strange that pressing ESC and calling 'close()' would get different results. Can you use this watermark instead? https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim And here is an example on my site: http://the.deerchao.net/PlaceHolder

Comment: I've insert the watermark init func as you advice and now they are shown correctly. Still I'm puzzle how the dialog get cleared.